# Networkmanager spawns two players, why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my Network-manager script. It should connect to a random lobby and when it doesn't find any lobby's it creates a new one. After thad it picks a random spawn point and activates the camera and the script for each player.

I want to ask why it spawns two player and you control both but see only one camera?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NetworkManager : MonoBehaviour {

    SpawnSpot[] spawnSpots;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        spawnSpots = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<SpawnSpot> ();
        Connect ();
    }

    void Connect () {
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings ("GCE_Mk2");
    }

    void OnGUI () {
        GUILayout.Label (PhotonNetwork.connectionStateDetailed.ToString ());
    }

    void OnConnectedToMaster () {
        Debug.Log ("Connected");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom ();
    }

    void OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed () {
        Debug.Log ("OnPhotonRandomJoinFailed");
        PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom (null);
    }

    void OnJoinedRoom() {
        Debug.Log ("OnJoinedRoom");

        SpawnMyPlayer ();
    }

    void SpawnMyPlayer () {
        if (spawnSpots == null) {
            Debug.LogError ("No Spawns");
            return;
        }

        SpawnSpot mySpawnSpot = spawnSpots [Random.Range (0, spawnSpots.Length)];
        GameObject myPlayerGO = (GameObject)PhotonNetwork.Instantiate ("RigidBodyFPSController", mySpawnSpot.transform.position, mySpawnSpot.transform.rotation, 0);
        ((MonoBehaviour)myPlayerGO.GetComponent ("RigidbodyFirstPersonController")).enabled = true;
        myPlayerGO.transform.FindChild ("MainCamera").gameObject.SetActive (true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Just debug why SpawnPlayer is called twice, I bet this is the problem, or your prefab already has double player.

Comment: I am using Unity for 1 - 2 months now. How can i do thad? Is thad a debug.(something)?

Comment: @lenny1999, No debug is a method to check your code. Attach a debugger to your code and see what happens. If you're using Visual Studio just attach a breakpoint to your code. Otherwise in Monostudio try something like `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`